# find the first element that has repeated N times in R

Tags: r

I need to find the first element that repeated "N" times, and "N" may change. For example, the elements are:

```
test <- c("A","B","B","C","A","A","C","C","C")
```

If `N=2`, it should return `"B"`.

If `N=3`, it should return `"A"`.

I have seen similar questions, but I need to only return the first element which repeated "N" times, and then stop. Many thanks.

(I made this example to represent a real work problem in an experimental chemistry study, where we have to find the re-occurrence of something.But the numbers of re-occurrence to be considered always change! Thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using `data.table` could be:

```
fun <- function(x) {test[which.max(rowid(test) == x)]}

fun(2)

[1] "B"

fun(3)

[1] "A"

fun(4)

[1] "C"
```

Or the same idea with just `base R`:

```
fun <- function(x) {test[which.max(ave(test, test, FUN = seq_along) == x)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun way, probably a lot slower than tmfmnk's  `ave(... seq_along...)` approach

```
foo <- rle(sort(text))
```

Then if `N` appears more than once in `foo$lengths` ,

```
items <- foo$values[which(foo$lengths == N)]
```

Then for all values in `items`,  grab `min(which(text==items[k])` and the smallest value you get will tell you the character that shows up first and occurs N times.